# ASUS N750JK internal speaker doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, sound

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on my asus n750jk but the internal speaker doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In Sound Settings change "Digital Output(S/PDIF)" to "Speakers"